# Making different groups/layers for with markers on Google Maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I just started using the Google Maps API, but I am using it through a asp.net control http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

But I am a bit in doubt, is it possible for me create categories / layers (Some sort of collection) where I can put markers on, and then have a Checkbox for each category to show/hide it or should I do that in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can make different arrays in JavaScript containing all the points you want for a particular "layer" and just add the array based on what radio button is pressed.

check this out [skyhawk](http://robinsone.com/skyhawk)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, everything is possible! :-)
This mashup has fast food restaurants grouped by brand:

http://gis5.com/pois_along_route/gm_pois_along_route.php